# Question about reincarnation

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, money, reincarnation, baal-shem-tov

I once heard a Rabbi recount a story of the Baal Shem Tov. A student of the Baal Shem Tov witnessed a rich man leave some money in an area, a poor man found it and took it.  The student asked the Baal Shem Tov the meaning of this and was answered, the rich man had robbed the poor man in a previous life.

My question is: if one is robbed how can they know if this is a debt they owe from a past life or not?

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiair with your question, nor is the kabbalistic concept of gilgul my field of expertise. However, it might be interesting to know that one of the main purposes of reincarnation is to do a tikkun, rectification for sin. [See this article written by Rabbi Nissan Dovid Dubov from Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/361889/jewish/Reincarnation.htm):

> Souls may also be reincarnated to complete a certain task, repay a debt, or rectify a sin. In fact the concept of reincarnation as rectification for sin is well documented by the Kabbalists.

And in [Derech HaShem, written by Rabbi Moshe Chaim Luzzatto, also known as the Ramchal](https://www.sefaria.org/Derekh_HaShem%2C_Part_Two%2C_On_Personal_Providence.10?ven=Sefaria_Edition_2019,_Translated_by_Rabbi_Francis_Nataf.&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it is explained that whatever happenend in the previous life, can happen during the reincarnation.

> And behold it is possible that matters will occur to a person whose soul was reincarnated according to that which was caused to it from the angle of what it did in a previous incarnation.

The story you mention shares a connection with a story I found involving something that Rav Chaim Kanievsky told. See the story from Torah-Box - [Rav Kanievsky’s Story: “The Soul of Your Borrower Reincarnated in a Donkey”](https://www.torah-box.net/jewish-ethics-and-learning/jewish-ethics/rav-kanievsky-s-story-the-soul-of-your-borrower-reincarnated-in-a-donkey_1380.html)